# Play movie in AVPlayerLayer inside UIImagePickerController's cameraOverlayView property

Tags: objective-c, ios

I would like to play a transparent movie in a AVPlayerLayer. But I want this layer to be in the cameraOverlayView property of the UIImagePickerController. The problem is that when the movie plays, camera closes. How should I do this correctly?